# Using Routing to return a WebForms page

Tags: c#, webforms, asp.net-core, asp.net-routing, asp.net-core-mvc

If I have a simple Default.aspx WebForms page under Views/WebForms/Default.aspx, how do I configure the MVC routing to open the Default.aspx page at startup?

I've tried reading some articles regarding the MVC 6 routing, but I don't think they're mentioning anything about incorporating WebForms routing with the new MVC 6. (I know WebForms is kind of deprecated but still supported in ASP.NET 5)

Articles:

- http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2015/02/07/asp-net-5-deep-dive-routing
- http://www.strathweb.com/2015/01/asp-net-mvc-6-attribute-routing-controller-action-tokens/

I think I have to use the IApplicationBuilder.UseRouter method, but not sure how to accomplish that.

Here's what I have attempted:

```
RouteCollection routes = new RouteCollection();
routes.Add(new TemplateRoute(new WebFormsRouterHandler(), "test", null));
app.UseRouter(routes);
```

And here's the WebFormsRouterHandler:

```
public class WebFormsRouterHandler : IRouter
{
    public string GetVirtualPath(VirtualPathContext context)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task RouteAsync(RouteContext context)
    {

    }
}
```

I'm not sure what to put in RouteAsync method..return the WebForms perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no support in ASP.NET 5 for Web Forms or the ASPX view engine.

What you can do is redirect to a WebForm application on .NET 4.5/4.6, or better yet port your default.aspx to razor.

As for the answer above - ASP.NET 5 does not yet support Web Pages. We have prototyped it and plan to have it in one of the releases after V1 RTM.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET 5 doesn't support `WebForms`but `WebPages` which use Razor syntax